# How do I scale an arcsegment in XAML without using Viewbox

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to scale an arcsegment similarly to how the linesegment is scaled. I don't want to use Viewbox since this will increase/decrease the line thickness as the window is resized. In my example I have a line segment that is scaled appropriately and I'd like to scale the arc segment similarly. How can this be done in XAML?

```
<UserControl x:Class="TMUI.UserControls.Chart"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TMUI"
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:TMUI.Converters"
        xmlns:bc="clr-namespace:TMUI.BindingConverters"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TMUI.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Visibility="{Binding BBMainMenuVisibility}" >

<Grid x:Name="grid" Background="Black">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ScaleTransform x:Key="transform"
                    ScaleX="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=grid}"
                    ScaleY="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=grid}"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Path Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1">
        <Path.Data>
            <LineGeometry StartPoint="0.01,0.01" EndPoint="0.99,0.99"
                        Transform="{StaticResource transform}"/>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>

    <Path Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigureCollection>
                        <PathFigure StartPoint="10,20">
                            <PathFigure.Segments>
                                <PathSegmentCollection>
                                    <ArcSegment Size="40,30" RotationAngle="45" IsLargeArc="True" SweepDirection="CounterClockwise" Point="100,100"/>
                                </PathSegmentCollection>
                            </PathFigure.Segments>
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathFigureCollection>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would scale the PathGeometry in the same way you scaled the LineGeometry, i.e. by assigning a ScaleTransform to its `Transform` property.

When you use the same ScaleTransform as for the LineGeometry, you would also need to use the same coordinate range from 0 to 1.

```
<Path Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry Transform="{StaticResource transform}">
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigureCollection>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="0.1,0.2">
                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                            <PathSegmentCollection>
                                <ArcSegment Size="0.4,0.3" Point="1,1"
                                            RotationAngle="45" IsLargeArc="True"
                                            SweepDirection="CounterClockwise"/>
                            </PathSegmentCollection>
                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathFigureCollection>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

You may also draw a single Path with multiple geometries in a GeometryGroup:

```
<Path Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1">
    <Path.Data>
        <GeometryGroup Transform="{StaticResource transform}">
            <LineGeometry StartPoint="0.01,0.01" EndPoint="0.99,0.99"/>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    ...
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </GeometryGroup>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Comment: Thanks. When I build and run the arc shows up fine. Is there a reason I cannot see the rendered arc in design view? In addition, If I comment out the linegeometry portion of the XAML and leave the arcsegment portion, the design view shows the arc skipping from top to bottom in the design view.  This behavior is strange.

Comment: It appears the reason for the render issues was the arc was outside the bounds defined by the line segment. If I change size to "0.3,0.4" and point to "0.7,0.9" and sweep direction to "Clockwise" then the arc is inside the bounds and I don't have any render issues.